# Почему ёмкость flash-памяти измеряют в *битах?

Tags: железо, flash-память

С микросхемами flash-памяти пока не работал, работа только предстоит, и её надо сейчас выбрать. Почему производители указывают ёмкость памяти в мега- и гигабитах? Мегабиты имеют смысл, когда не нужно оперировать с байтами или словами, например, при последовательной передаче данных. А здесь всё равно потребитель информации будет работать со словами. Какой тогда смысл в мегабитах?

Comment: Рекламный ход, как цена 999 руб. 99 коп. или как молоко в пакете 900 гр.

Comment: Рискну предположить, что исторически так сложилось. И не только с FLASH.

Comment: Ни один из комментариев и ответ не указывают на то, что память на уровне железа может иметь разную организацию т.е. количество блоков и их размер, в зависимости от организации возможны варианты интеграции с разными шинами данных. Например, 8Mb (64Mbit) может быть представлено как 4Mbit X 16, может как 8Mbit X 8, а может и как 16Mbit X 4.

Comment: @0andriy, почему вы всегда оформляете правильный ответ как комментарий? Ваш ответ меня устраивает, и если вы его напишете как ответ и чуть более подробно, я отмечу его как верный.

Answer (score 0):

Флэш-память хранит информацию в ячейках (массиве транзисторов с плавающим затвором), которые могут хранить только один бит на одну ячейку, так было изначально на первых флэшках. По мере развития технологий значения поменялись на мегабайты и гигабайты.

Comment: *Различают приборы, в которых элементарная ячейка хранит один бит информации и несколько бит. В однобитовых ячейках различают только два уровня заряда на плавающем затворе. Такие ячейки называют одноуровневыми (single-level cell, SLC). В многобитовых ячейках различают больше уровней заряда; их называют многоуровневыми (multi-level cell, MLC[3][4])*

Comment: Ну да, я это и имел в ввиду. Только вы дали более расширенный ответ.